# Convert Date object to milliseconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime, time

Here I have an function:

```
timeline.getDataRange();
```

which give me this result:

```
Object {min: Sun Dec 31 1899 14:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central Europe Standard Time), max: Fri Dec 13 2013 15:07:22 GMT+0100 (Central Europe Standard Time)}
max: Fri Dec 13 2013 15:07:22 GMT+0100 (Central Europe Standard Time)
min: Sun Dec 31 1899 14:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central Europe Standard Time)
__proto__: Object
```

Now I want to convert this dates (`min` and `max`) into milliseconds

I try this:

```
function startEndSec () {
        var myDate = timeline.getDataRange();
        var pocetak = myDate[0].getTime();
        return pocetak; 
    }
```

but console say: `Cannot call method 'getTime' of undefined`

How I can convert this dates (min,max) into milliseconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to treat `myDate` as an array, but it is an object literal. Use the object keys

```
var minDate=new Date( myDate.min).getTime();
```

I can't tell if you have strings or `date` objects in `myDate`.

If they are already `date` objects you only need `myDate.min.getTime()`

Comment: I try: function startEndSec () {
  var myDate = timeline.getVisibleChartRange();
  var pocetak = new Date( myDate.min).getTime();
  return pocetak; 
 } but in console I get NaN ????

Comment: It's an object, not an object *literal*, and they are already `Date` objects, otherwise it wouldn't look like that (without quotes around the property values). The thing in the question that looks like an object literal is what's displayed in the Chrome console or other JavaScript debugger. For example, paste `({ min: new Date, max: new Date })` into the Chrome console and you'll see something very much like what's in the question.

Comment: If you are getting strings, this is a little more succinct (notice the +new Date() idiom returns milliseconds): var dateRangeMap, minTime, maxTime; dateRangeMap = timeline.getDataRange(); minTime = +new Date( dateRangeMap.min ); maxTime = +new Date( dateRangeMap.max );

Comment: @MichaelMikowski  read the subject...OP wants milliseconds = getTime()

Comment: @charlietfl try the code; it returns milliseconds, just like the OP requested.

Comment: @MichaelMikowski my bad...apologies...guess I just learned something new about date object

Comment: @charlietfl No worries.  Thanks for the feedback.  And, yes, the +new... idiom is probably too clever by half ;)